# Localhost says upgrade required

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I am working on a web rtc project. I have create four files: index.html, server.js, client.js and package.json. My server is node.js. When I input node server.js, it produces nothing. Then, when i write on my web browser localhost:8080, it says upgrade required. Any solution? Please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unlikely we can help you without a lot more details including at least some relevant portion of your code.  Have you done any debugging on  your server code to see if it is running and receiving http requests from your browser?  Do you know where the "upgrade required" message is coming from?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading?

Comment: no its from the browser

Comment: How can i upgrade?

Comment: Upgrade of what?  Browser?  node.js?  Client OS?  Server OS?  Way too little info to have any idea how to help you.  Since you may be new here, it is your responsibility to post a complete question that describes your problem in enough detail that we (who know nothing about what you're trying to accomplish or the code you've written so far) could actually help you.  Incomplete questions that are not immediately edited to provide missing detail will be downvoted and closed (that's how stack overflow works).  I'd recommend you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: He's trying to tell you that after he starts his server, he gets no console messages (the server doesn't log anything to the console, so it's difficult to tell if it's actually started)., then connects with his browser, all he sees is the message "Upgrade Required" in his browser... His question is What does he need to upgrade? The answer below is the correct answer... the server is listening but doesn't have websocket running.

Answer (score 7):

This means that you have a http server listening on 8080 without websocket capabilities. Your webrtc client needs websocket to be able to talk with the server. You need also socket.io. Example:

```
// Require HTTP module (to start server) and Socket.IO
var http = require('http'), io = require('socket.io');

// Start the server at port 8080
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 

    // Send HTML headers and message
    res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
    res.end('<h1>Hello Socket Lover!</h1>');
});
server.listen(8080);

// Create a Socket.IO instance, passing it our server
var socket = io.listen(server);

// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 

    // Success!  Now listen to messages to be received
    client.on('message',function(event){ 
        console.log('Received message from client!',event);
    });
    client.on('disconnect',function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log('Server has disconnected');
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

This means that you have an http server listening on 8080 without WebSocket capabilities. Your webrtc client needs a WebSocket to be able to talk with the server. You need also socket.io. Example:

```js
// Require HTTP module (to start server) and Socket.IO
var http = require('http'), io = require('socket.io');

// Start the server at port 8080
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 

    // Send HTML headers and message
    res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
    res.end('<h1>Hello Socket Lover!</h1>');
});
server.listen(8080);

// Create a Socket.IO instance, passing it our server
var socket = io.listen(server);

// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 

    // Success!  Now listen to messages to be received
    client.on('message',function(event){ 
        console.log('Received message from client!',event);
    });
    client.on('disconnect',function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log('Server has dis
```