# nodejs says Upgrade required

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs. I was just creating a code that accepts and sends it back with a new message. But when I run using localhost:3000 - it says Upgrade required. I read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973081/localhost-says-upgrade-required) But as a beginner, I don't understand What they said. I don't know what to do?
[image]
when I run it shows "it's working".

Comment: Which IDE are you using for coding in nodejs? I think you should upgrade it from its website.

Comment: Try installing the latest Nodejs from their official website. 
https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: I am using Visual studio code and it says no updates available. Are you sure that's the error?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot where it says *Upgrade required*?

Comment: If you are opening localhost:3000 in a browser then of course it's not gonna work. You need a websocket client to connect to your server, browser is not gonna do it for you.

Comment: So what to do then ?

Comment: photo added in question @Molda

Comment: **Find a tutorial** on how to write a websocket client. **Do some research** and then when you have some problem come back. **You do not have any problem** right now other then the fact that you haven't spend enough time **learning how things work**.

Comment: just tested with websocket test client. it works. thanks

Comment: This could be edited into a great question for those starting out with websockets and visiting the websocket URL in the browser